# Generic function to Map Datatable to List Using Custom attribute

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Following is my code, where I convert data table to List of class

```
       var cities = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(c => new City
                {
                    CityCode = c.Field<object>("CITY_CODE"),
                    CityMid = c.Field<object>("CITY_MID"),
                    CityName = c.Field<object>("CITY_NAME"),
                    CountryCode = c.Field<object>("COUNTRY_CODE"),
                    StateCode = c.Field<object>("STATE_CODE"),
                    ActiveFlag = c.Field<object>("ACTIVE_FLG"),
                }).ToList();
```

How can one create a generic class to convert data-table or map to list, In the above example, I have used the class City, but there will be any class with different properties and data-table with any column names

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "with any class"? Could you show an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: `public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetCities(Func<DataRow, TEntity> selector)`

Comment: @DaisyShipton any class means, I am trying to make common method so that if i used another class say Employee then it should give me the ouput I required

Comment: @Satsvelke: So you'd pass in a `Func<DataRow, Employee>`... I'm still not sure what's missing here. That's why I asked for an example of what you're trying to achieve - what code do you want to be able to write? (Basically take nvoigt's answer, but make it generic: `public IEnumerable<T> GetValues<T>(Func<DataRow, T> selector)`

Comment: I will Edit the question, give me time

Answer (score 3):

The datatype is `Func<DataRow, City>`, a function that takes a `DataRow` and returns a `City`:

```
public IEnumerable<City> GetCities(Func<DataRow, City> selector)
{
    return ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(selector).ToList();
}
```

Call it like

```
var cities = GetCities(c => new City     
{
    CityCode = c.Field<object>("CITY_CODE"),
    CityMid = c.Field<object>("CITY_MID"),
    CityName = c.Field<object>("CITY_NAME"),
    CountryCode = c.Field<object>("COUNTRY_CODE"),
    StateCode = c.Field<object>("STATE_CODE"),
    ActiveFlag = c.Field<object>("ACTIVE_FLG"),
});
```

or use another variable of said type:

```
Func<DataRow, City> myfunc = c => new City     
{
    CityCode = c.Field<object>("CITY_CODE"),
    CityMid = c.Field<object>("CITY_MID"),
    CityName = c.Field<object>("CITY_NAME"),
    CountryCode = c.Field<object>("COUNTRY_CODE"),
    StateCode = c.Field<object>("STATE_CODE"),
    ActiveFlag = c.Field<object>("ACTIVE_FLG"),
};

var cities = GetCities(myfunc);
```

If your class is not only `City` but different classes, you can use generics:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetCities(Func<DataRow, T> selector)
{
    return ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(selector).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Yes! Becuase the asker uses `.AsEnumerable()`, the type of the lambda expression will be `Func<DataRow, City>` as you say. Without the `.AsEnumerable`, another Linq provider could become relevant, and that provider may need an expression tree and not a plain delegate. The type in that case would be `Expression<Func<DataRow, City>>`. The latter overload of `.Select` is declared by the `IQueryable<>` interface, while the one with the plain delegate is declared by its base interface `IEnumerable<>`. Not sure if this helps the asker or not; he did mention the word "Expression" with a capital E.

Comment: actually the City class and its properties are dynamic, the class can be Employee

Comment: @Satsvelke You can use generics for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

> What I have know I have to return the Expression, but I just don't understand that how can I do that with any class?

`c => new City { ... }` is a `delegate` of type `Func<DataRow, City>` that is somehow equivalent to a Method that gets a `DataRow` and returns a `City`. So you can create a method for it.

```
City ConvertToCity(DataRow row) =>
        new City
        {
            CityCode = row.Field<object>("CITY_CODE"),
            CityMid = row.Field<object>("CITY_MID"),
            CityName = row.Field<object>("CITY_NAME"),
            CountryCode = row.Field<object>("COUNTRY_CODE"),
            StateCode = row.Field<object>("STATE_CODE"),
            ActiveFlag = row.Field<object>("ACTIVE_FLG"),
        };
```

and then pass the method to the `Select` function:

```
var cities = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(ConvertToCity).ToList();
```